# How do we derive the expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am studying a book which gives the following expressions:

$\alpha = \frac{\beta_1 d}{2} + \frac{\beta_2 d}{2}$ and $\gamma = \frac{\beta_1 d}{2n} - \frac{\beta_2 d}{2n}$.

Then it needs to solve for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ when we know $\alpha, \gamma, d, n$.

It then says that adding these two expressions gives: $2\alpha + 2n\gamma = 2\beta_1 d$ (which I don't understand how it gets there) and then it solves for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ like so:

- $\beta_1 = \frac{\alpha + n \gamma}{d}$
- $\beta_2 = \frac{\alpha - n \gamma}{d}$

I don't understand how it gets to these, and it does not explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \frac{\beta_1 d}{2} + \frac{\beta_2 d}{2}$ and $\gamma = \frac{\beta_1 d}{2n} - \frac{\beta_2 d}{2n}$.

Then
$$2\alpha = \beta_1d + \beta_2d$$
and $$2n\gamma = \beta_1d - \beta_2d$$

If we add $2\alpha$ to $2n\gamma$, it's the same as adding what's on the right hand side:

$$2\alpha + 2n\gamma = \beta_1d  + \beta_1d + \beta_2d - \beta_2d = 2\beta_1 d$$

This is how they derived
$$2\alpha + 2n\gamma =  2\beta_1 d$$

Now, we want to find $\beta_1$. Let's divide both sides above by $2d$. Then we get:

$$\beta_1 = \frac{\alpha + n \gamma}{d}$$

To get $\beta_2$, we plug this in to $\gamma = \frac{\beta_1 d}{2n} - \frac{\beta_2 d}{2n}$. Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $2$ in the $\alpha$ expression, and $2n$ in the $\gamma$ expression. Then add them, bearing mind how to collect like terms. You get

$$2\alpha + 2 n \gamma = \underbrace{\beta_1 d + \beta_2 d}_{=2\alpha} + \underbrace{\beta_1 d - \beta_2 d}_{=2n\gamma} = 2 \beta_1 d$$

Solve for $\beta_1$ in this expression by dividing both sides by $2d$.

$$\beta_1 = \frac{2\alpha + 2n\gamma}{2d} = \frac{\alpha + n \gamma}{d}$$

This holds by cancelling the common factor of $2$ in the numerator and denominator.

---

Repeat this process from the start, but find $2\alpha - 2n\gamma$ instead. You will get $2 \beta_2 d$. Solve the resulting expression for $\beta_2$ in the same manner.

*Edit:* Alternatively, plug in your result for $\beta_1$ into the equation $\gamma = \frac{\beta_1 d}{2n} - \frac{\beta_2 d}{2n}$, and then solve for $\beta_2$. Both methods work.